# Faceted bar charts from multiple columns in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet

I have some data containing resistance data against three different antibiotics, each stored as a column.

```
Isolate MIC1    MIC2     MIC3
    1   0.008   0.064   0.064
    2   0.016   0.250   0.500
    3   0.064   0.125   32
...
```

I've plotted barcharts for each individual antibiotic thus:

```
ggplot(data, aes(factor(MIC1))) + geom_bar()
```

(the values are discrete as powers of 2 - 0.008, 0.016, 0.032 etc - plotting as factor evenly spaces the bars, if there more elegant way of doing this, please let me know!)

What I'd really like to do is to have a faceted stack of the three graphs with a shared x-axis.

Is there an easier way to do this than to recode the variables like this:

```
isolate  antibiotic  MIC
    1        1       0.008
    1        2       0.064
    1        3       0.064
    2        1       0.016
    2        2       0.250
    2        3       0.500
    3        1       0.064
    3        2       0.125
    3        3       32
...
```

and then doing it this way?

```
ggplot(data, aes(factor(MIC))) + geom_bar() + facet_grid(antibiotic ~ .)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshaping your data frame to look like your second example is pretty easy using `reshape2`, to the point where I'm not sure it could really get much easier. Are there any specific problems you would have with this solution?

```
df = read.table(text="Isolate MIC1    MIC2     MIC3
    1   0.008   0.064   0.064
    2   0.016   0.250   0.500
    3   0.064   0.125   32", header=TRUE)

library(reshape2)
df_melted = melt(df, id.vars="Isolate", variable.name="antibiotic", value.name="MIC")
ggplot(df_melted, aes(factor(MIC))) + geom_bar() + facet_grid(antibiotic ~ .)
```

Comment: Thanks very much;   I suspected that was going to be the easiest way to do it, I'm just not familiar with reshape.